# Selecting a Revit Element by the ID taken from WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api

Before jumping straight to the problem, I will shortly describe what I am trying to code. Basically, I am trying to do a Revit Add-In which opens a WPF Dialog, shows the `id` and `categoryName` of the elements in the active view and when double-clicked on a cell containing the `id`, the dialog closes and the element with that `id` is selected.

The problem arises after I double-click. Because the `Execute()` command ends after the dialog is shown, I am no longer able to perform the `Selection`.

**Command.cs**

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
   public class Command : IExternalCommand
   {
      static List<Element> elemList = new List<Element>();

      public Result Execute(
        ExternalCommandData commandData,
        ref string message,
        ElementSet elements)
      {
         UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
         UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
         Application app = uiapp.Application;
         Document doc = uidoc.Document;

         //List<Element> elemList = new List<Element>();

         FilteredElementCollector allElementsInView = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id);
         IList elementsInView = (IList)allElementsInView.ToElements();

         foreach (Element elem in elementsInView)
         {
            elemList.Add(elem);
         }

         OpenDialog();

         return Result.Succeeded;
      }
      
      public static void SelectElementById(ElementId id)
      {

      }

      public static List<Element> SendElements()
      {
         return elemList;
      }

      public void OpenDialog()
      {
         ElementListDialog dialog = new ElementListDialog();

         dialog.Show();
      }

   }
}
```

As you can see above, I also have a `SelectElementById(...)` method which is called from the **ElementListDialog.xaml.cs** class. Below you will see the functionality for populating the `DataGrid` and the `MouseButtonDoubleClick` method which gets the cell's value and passes the `id` of type `ElementId` back to **Command.cs**

**ElementListDialog.xaml.cs**

```
private List<Element> elemList;
      public ElementListDialog()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         Lab8.Command.SendElements();
         elemList = Lab8.Command.SendElements();

         //elemList = _elemList;

         Content content = new Content();

         foreach (var elem in elemList)
         {
            content = new Content();
            content.id = elem.Id;
            content.categName = elem.Category.Name;

            var finalList = new Content
            {
               id = content.id,
               categName = content.categName
            };
            
            ElementDataGrid.Items.Add(finalList);
            
         }
      }

      private void ElementDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
         var grid = sender as DataGrid;

         var cellValue = grid.SelectedValue;
         Content content = new Content();

         content = (Content)cellValue;
         
         Command.SelectElementById(content.id);
      }
```

Therefore; how should I design the `SelectElementById` method such that I am able to select a certain element by the `id`? Or does the current code not allow this to be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current code is fine. You need to get the active view and use a transaction to set the element in the current view

```
public static void SelectElementById(ElementId id)
    {
        ICollection<ElementId> to_showids = new List<ElementId>();
        to_showids.Add(id);

        //RESET ELEMENTS IN VIEW
        var itrans = new Transaction(YOURDOCUMENT, "Show Element");
        using(itrans)
        {
            itrans.Start();
            //The below step is to make sure that any previous selection is removed and only your new selection is set.
            YOURDOC_UI.Selection.SetElementIds(to_showids);
            itrans.Commit();
        }

        //SHOW ELEMENTS
        YOURDOC_UI.ShowElements(to_showids);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! However, I can't figure out how to call `YOURDOCUMENT` and `YOURDOC_UI` from the `Execute` method. Got any tips on that?

Comment: I tried something myself but I am getting this error on `itrans.Start();` : `Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: 'Starting a transaction from an external application running outside of API context is not allowed.'`

Comment: I removed the transaction and worked well. Your help is highly appreciated, once again! I am still curious how could I have made it work with the transaction?

Comment: YOURDOCUMENT and YOURDOC_UI are basically place holders. You need your UIDocument and Document there. You can store them in any static property (so that it can be accessed globally). When you invoke your IExternalApplication you will get the document and you can store them.

Comment: As far as transaction is concerned, i missed to notice that the dialog closes and then the method is called (which makes it outside API context). May be you can create a generic Command with an Action or Func property. Before calling the command each time, you can just set these delegate properties with your actual method and invoke them. So that all calls falls inside the Revit API context.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting an element or some UI interactions do not require transactions.
If you however want to change an element property in datagrid and apply changes in revit then you will need transaction.

You can run your WPF window on a different thread in order not to block Revit UI.
Then you can use IExternalEventHandler to execute code in the valid Revit API context

```
class DoSomethingOnEventRaised : IExternalEventHandler
{
    public void Execute(UIApplication uiapp)
    {
        //code to be executed in API context
    }
}

IExternalEventHandler doSomethingEvHandler = new DoSomethingOnEventRaised();
ExternalEvent doSomethingEvent = ExternalEvent.Create(calculationSupport);

doSomethingEvent.Raise() will execute the code
```